# OnClick siempre hace la función en el primer item ¿Por qué?

Tags: java, android

Tengo dos botones dentro de mi `CardView`, el primero borra la `CardView` y los datos de mi database, este funciona correctamente. Según en que item le des al botón lo borra correctamente.

```
holder.myButtonDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //Query deleteQuery = databaseReference.child("personas").orderByChild("name").equalTo(personasList.get(position).toString());
                databaseReference.child("Personas").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                            Personas personasTemp = snapshot.getValue(Personas.class);
                            if (personas.getDatospersona().equals(personasTemp.getDatospersona())) {
                                databaseReference.child("Personas").child(snapshot.getKey().toString()).removeValue();
                                personasList.remove(position);
                                notifyDataSetChanged();
                                if (personasList.size() == 0) {
                                    VerPersonasAdministrador.textViewEmptyView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                }
                                break;

                            }

                        }

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
```

Y este es mi otro botón, que sirve para cambiar el *valor* `true` por `false` del *atributo* `esNuevo`, el problema es que le des al botón en el item que le des, siempre hace la acción en el primer item.

```
holder.myButtonNuevo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //Query deleteQuery = databaseReference.child("personas").orderByChild("name").equalTo(personasList.get(position).toString());
                databaseReference.child("Personas").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                            Personas personasTemp = snapshot.getValue(Personas.class);
                            if (personas.getDatospersona().equals(personasTemp.getDatospersona())) {
                                databaseReference.child("Personas").child(snapshot.getKey().toString());
                                snapshot.getRef().child("esNuevo").setValue(false);
                                notifyDataSetChanged();
                                if (personasList.size() == 0) {
                                    VerPersonasAdministrador.textViewEmptyView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                }
                                break;

                            }

                        }

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Hola me parece que el problema es donde estas definiendo los listeners. Tienes algún mensaje en el LogCat?

Comment: Nop, como ya te digo, en el primer item funciona perfecto, pero si le das al boton en los demas item hacen la funcion pero en el primer item, aunque le des al 2,3,4... @Jorgesys

Comment: entonces el problema no es el Click, te sugiero agregues revises si en realidad se ejecuta el onClick(). @UserNameYo

Comment: Eso te pasa luego de hacer el delete con el botón? O antes?. Otra cosa, asegurate de que estas instanciando correctamente los botones (asegurate de que no tengan el mismo ID).

Comment: Sin usar el botón delete, ya que ese funciona bien, el problema está en el segundo botón, que haga click desde el item que lo haga, siempre hace la función en el primer item. @Andrespengineer

Comment: Si lo que quieres es cambiar un valor de una persona, por qué no le guardas el Key en el objeto `Personas`, cuando estés halando la data de esa persona. Es decir, creas un campo `Key` en el objeto `Personas` con su Getter and Setter y en su objeto pones ejemplo: `Personas persona = snapshot.getValue(Personas.class):` `persona.setKey(snapshot.getKey());` luego `personasList.add(persona)`, asi solo tendrias que llamar a la referencia child de firebase del Key de ese objeto en vez de iterar la lista completa y comparar. El problema creo que es que la variable `personas` no tiene el valor correcto

Comment: Gracias por tu comentario @Andrespengineer pero ya lo he conseguido solucionar, ahora agrego mi solución! Gracias igualmente :)

Comment: Dale, no estaría de más hacer lo que te dije. Se verá mucho reflejado en la complejidad y el ahorro de carga de datos adicional a tu aplicación.

Comment: Le echaré un ojo! Si puedes pásate por esta pregunta que acabo de crear, gracias de nuevo :) @Andrespengineer https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/75147/a%C3%B1adir-item-nuevo-siempre-el-primero-recyclerview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finalmente lo he conseguido solucionar.

El problema era que no obtenía `getKey` por lo tanto siempre se hacía el cambio en la misma *Persona*

Así que quitando esto que no servía

```
databaseReference.child("Personas").child(snapshot.getKey().toString());
snapshot.getRef().child("esNuevo").setValue(false);
```

Por:

```
databaseReference.child("Personas").child(snapshot.getKey().toString()).child("esNuevo").setValue(false);
```

Ya obtengo `getKey` y ya no tengo problemas!

Answer (score 0):

Asegura que estos listener los definas dentro del constructor de tu clase `ViewHolder` :

```
class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        ...
        ...
        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        ...
          holder.myButtonDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        ...
          holder.myButtonNuevo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        ...
```

Comment: entonces el problema no es el Click, te sugiero agregues revises si en realidad se ejecuta el onClick().

Comment: Si se ejecuta el onClick pero siempre hace la función en el primer item le des al item que le des @Jorgesys he editado la pregunta, me puedes ayudar?