# Añadir item nuevo siempre el primero (RecyclerView)

Tags: java, android

Cómo puedo hacer para que todos los item`s que vaya añadiendo se vayan poniendo en primera posición? Ahora mismo el que añado siempre se pone el último.

Este es mi `Adapter`:

```
public class PersonasAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PersonasAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private final Context mContext;
    DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    private List<Personas> personasList = new ArrayList<>();

    public PersonasAdapter(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
    }

    public void setData(List<Personas> personas) {
        personasList.clear();
        personasList.addAll(personas);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public PersonasAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.personas_list_item, parent, false);
        return new MyViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final PersonasAdapter.MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        final Personas personas = personasList.get(position);

        holder.textViewNuevo.setVisibility(personas.getEsNuevo()==true? View.VISIBLE:View.GONE);
        holder.myTextView.setText(personas.getDatospersona());
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(mContext, " " + personasList.get(position).toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        holder.myButtonDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                databaseReference.child("Personas").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                            Personas personasTemp = snapshot.getValue(Personas.class);
                            if (personas.getDatospersona().equals(personasTemp.getDatospersona())) {
                                databaseReference.child("Personas").child(snapshot.getKey().toString()).removeValue();
                                personasList.remove(position);
                                notifyDataSetChanged();
                                if (personasList.size() == 0) {
                                    VerPersonasAdministrador.textViewEmptyView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                }
                                break;

                            }

                        }

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return personasList.size();
    }

    public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public TextView myTextView;
        public Button myButtonDelete;
        public ImageView textViewNuevo;

        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            myTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvDatospersona);
            myButtonDelete = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.deleteButton);
            textViewNuevo = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvNuevo);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: cuando haces tu setData, mandas una lista de personas, limpias la lista y lo copias, asi que, donde estes llamando a tu setData, al arreglo que mandas de parametro, agrega el item primero con add(0,persona), por que en algun lado rellenaras ese arreglo, asi que donde lo estes rellenando, ahi es donde debes de validar eso

Comment: Para esto simplemente invierte los datos que alimentan tu Adapter , usando Collections.reverse(lista); agregué respuesta @UserNameYo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

los elementos los añades en la personas en el setData, recorre la lista insertando en la posición 0 y así estarás insertando en cabeza.
En lugar de:

```
 public void setData(List<Personas> personas) {
    personasList.clear();
    personasList.addAll(personas);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

usa

```
public void setDAta(List<personas> personas) {
    personalList.clear();
    for(Personas p : personas) {
       personasList.add(0, p);
    }
    notifiDataSetChanged();
}
```

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html

Answer (score 1):

**Usa `Collections.reverse(list);` para cambiar el orden de los datos que alimentan tu Adapter**, de esta forma los últimos que son insertados se mostrarían primeramente.

por ejemplo si los datos los recibe tu método:

```
 public void setData(List<Personas> personas) {
        personasList.clear();
        personasList.addAll(personas);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

simplemente cambia el orden de la lista, ya sea de personas:

```
 public void setData(List<Personas> personas) {
        personasList.clear();

        Collections.reverse(personas); //***

        personasList.addAll(personas);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

o personasList:

```
 public void setData(List<Personas> personas) {
        personasList.clear();
        personasList.addAll(personas);

        Collections.reverse(personasList); //***

        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```